# Javascript match doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, preg-match

I have the following code.

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

Seems to work ok in FF and Chrome. IE comes up with  '1' is null or not an object. rgb value does seem to make it to the rgb.match.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: The values you're passing this function look like "rgb(12, 34, 56)" ?

Comment: i am passing a RGB colour and trying to convert it to hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out what rgb is before you run the regex. It might be that the *input* is different.

I'm assuming you're checking an `dom_element.style` property. Perhaps IE never converts that property to the `rgb(r, g, b)` format in the first place.

Comment: I added an alert() before the match and it does have a hex colour value so that seems ok.

Comment: yes you are correct it is being converted already where as FF and Chorme do not. thx