# jquery - .css not working gives a null value

Tags: jquery, css, background

I have an index that changes its template depending on what the user selects. I want the menu to change color too once the user changes its template. 
It works in all browsers but in IE it gives me the error  '1' is null or not an object in the line `return "#" + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]) + hex(bg[3]);`

here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var bg = convert(jQuery('#body').css('background-color'));
        var font = convert(jQuery('.left').css('color'));
        if(bg =='#ffffff' || bg=='undefined'){
            bg = '#000000';
            font='#ffffff';
        }


        jQuery('.mainmenu').hover(
            function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF' );
            },
            function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor'));
            }
        ); 
        jQuery('.submenu').hover(
            function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('bgcolor2', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', bg );
            },
            function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor2'));
            }
        );
        jQuery('.submenu2').hover(
            function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('color', $this.css('color')).css('color', font );
            },
            function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.css('color', $this.data('color'));
            }
        );
    });
    function convert(bg){
        bg = bg.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        return "#" + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]) + hex(bg[3]);
    }
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
</scri
```

Comment: Can you do a console.log on bg to see what it returns?

Comment: What happens when you declare `bg` and `font` outside the `ready` function and then define the `convert` method to use something other than "bg" as the parameter name?

Comment: @TLS i tried your suggestion it returned this ' '1' is null or not an object'

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how do i do a console.log sorry im kinda noob

Comment: i think the problem lies in this function.
`function convert(bg1){
   bg1 = bg1.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
   return "#" + hex(bg1[1]) + hex(bg1[2]) + hex(bg1[3]);
  }`

Comment: It's going to be hard to tell unless you separate those calls to `hex` onto different lines and then combine the results in the `return` line.  Try separating the `return` line in the `hex` function, as well, to see if it's one of the chained methods.  With separated method calls, you can check the values of each one and see where it's failing.

Comment: so after slicing it down maybe IE can't read this line thats why it gives me the error of 1 is null. after `bg1 = bg1.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);` IE cant read bg1[1]; i tried to alert bg1[1]; gives me an error of 1 is null. tried to alert bg1. gives me #aN.

Comment: @TLS thanks for the guide now i know the answer it is from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997344/javascript-match-doesnt-work-in-ie IE converts the rgb(0 0 0); values to hex automatically so .match doesnt work anymore. as a workaround ill have to detect what browser it is. :) thanks

Comment: Great!  You should answer your question with the link to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer from: [Javascript match doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997344/javascript-match-doesnt-work-in-ie) IE converts the rgb values to hex so .match is passing a different value.